# My printer in /dev/usb/lp0 always disappear after few seconds, and can't print, how to fix it? (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: linux, usb, printing, printer, udev

Please, help...

I have a 'EPPOS Model EPT-58H' thermal printer.
When I plugin via usb, it detected as `/dev/usb/lp0` with `ls -l /dev` command.
Then I run `echo "sometext" > /dev/usb/lp0` in terminal to check if my printer can actually print from my notebook, but nothing happened. The command itself seems succesfully executed, but my printer didn't print that `sometext`.

Then I tried to run `ls -l /dev/` again, my usb dissapear. It will show up again if I restart my printer.

Then I check with `dmesg` command, it shows that my printer didn't properly make connection with my notebook, it says ehci-pci error -32 or something like that.

I tried to install the driver from CUPS web on `localhost:631`, but I don't have any idea which one should works, you know, 'EPPOS' didn't even shown in the driver list.

Any idea how to solve this?
I've already search anywhere no clues about my printer issue.
Note, I did [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74565/how-to-print-both-from-the-command-line-as-well-as-through-cups) , and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1436079&page=2) (and the link inside, except using wine solution, didn't even want to)

**Just added** - according to @scai comment

I already test on another notebooks.
On mine, Sony Vaio, on others, Compaq, and Mac (this 3 using Ubuntu 14.04.3 64bit)
And on 1 notebook using FreeBSD.
A new PC with Ubuntu 14.04.3 64bit.

The thing is it can works using FreeBSD. While on the other 3 notebook and 1 PC didn't. It is seems always disconnect itself. So is it really the usb cable? Or something else? I'll try changing the cable.

*--end of added info--*

Any help will be appreciated, thank's.

Comment: Does it happen with different computers / operating systems, too? And what about a different USB cable? I recently had a quite similar issue with a USB extension cable and fixed it by connecting the printer directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give up trying this. It is not working either with 16.04 LTS which is using 4.4 linux kernel.

And on Windows 8.1 with proper driver ended with failed too.

Here I am finally using BSD (OpenBSD, NetBSD, and another BSD-based) succesfully working. On BSD, it is mounted as `ulpt0`.

It's a dead end trying on other Linux (Debian-based, Arch, RedHat, blabla).

So, at the end I use BSD to work this out.